# Style (.css) missing when added Azure Cloud Project

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I'm in my way to convert an existing web site to Azure Cloud Service Project, but when I add this cloud project and debug my the project, the web page is missing all the styling, i.e. all the tabs in one page. I have seen that doesn't take the .css

Someone could tell me what's happening here?
Thanks!

Comment: It's very difficult for us to answer if we can't see some code. Can you post an example of the relevant html and css, so we can get an idea of what may be happening?

Comment: There are for .cs classes in a folder, what maybe could be a problem is that I have copy the project from the ISS folder, and I didn't had the .csproj file, what do u think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and I found it came from my use of IIS Express.

The problem was an error that can be seen in Windows Application Logs:

Src: IIS Express

"The directory specified for caching compressed content [...] is invalid. Static compression is being disabled."

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that, I'll search more about it.

Answer (score 2):

Verify the *.css files, you need to make sure that the **Build Action** is set to **Content**:

[image]

Comment: I'm wondering if the web.config file could be a problem, as explained here, I have overwrite for the existing in the web site. (page 17) http://umbracoonazure.codeplex.com/releases/view/62302#DownloadId=215860

Comment: When I debug my project I see the web site correctly, and the calls are getting the .css correctly, I can navigate to http ://localhost:xxxxx/css/css_styles.css". 
But when I add the cloud project, doesn't get back the .css and I can't navigate to http ://xxx.x.x.x:yy but yes to xxx.x.x.x:yy, where I see my project without style.
I think I'm missing any configuration for Azure, because this happens when I add this project.
Hope someone could help me in that, thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

You can try changing the properties of the cloud project -> Web -> use IIS Web Server..
worked for me

Answer (score 0):

fist I don't know if I have to write this as answer, if not sorry, I'll correct it.

About my question, I tough in publish it to Azure and when i did it, was working correctly. What I still don't know is why when I debug in VS with the cloud project is missing style and images.